# How to Add Header and Footer to ListView (Android XE5)

Tags: android, listview, delphi-xe5

Help me with subject please. I can add Item to ListView 
(LItem := ListView.Items.Add), but how can I add Header And Footer?
In DELPHI XE5!. not JAVA.

Answer (score 4):

LItem := ListView.Items.Add;
LItem.Purpose:=TListItemPurpose.Footer;

Comment: never answer like that, must describe your approach regarding the issue. And do read FAQ before answering on this site

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem before. In my component, I want to add a pull down to refresh feature in my Listview. What I did is declaring the view layout in xml layout file, then in my ListView subclass, I use following code:

```
this.addHeaderView(headerRelativeLayout, null, false); //this is the ListView sub class
```

Here is my whole code:

```
private void init(Context context) {
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
headerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflate(context, R.layout.refresh_header_view, null);
arrowImage = (ImageView)headerRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.head_arrowImageView);
progressBar = (ProgressBar)headerRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.head_progressBar);
headerTextView = (TextView)headerRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.head_tipsTextView);
lastUpdateDateTextView = (TextView)headerRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.head_lastUpdatedDateTextView);

headerRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, -1 * HEADER_HEIGHT, 0, 0);
this.addHeaderView(headerRelativeLayout, null, false);
```

}

For more details, you can check this: [Drag to Refresh in ListView Android Example](http://jmsliu.com/1529/rss-reader-android-app-tutorial-4-drag-to-refresh-in-listview-android-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/background_bottom_bar"
        >

        <TextView
        android:text="Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/gridview_practioner"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:columnWidth="90dp"
         android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
         android:numColumns="5"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:text="Footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@color/background_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note :

here if you are using listview or gridview , you have to give listview or gridview weight =1.